# get last 5th day date from current date in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have the following table :

```
+----+-------------+
| ID | startDate   |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 2014-10-29  |
|  2 | 2014-10-29  |
|  3 | 2014-10-28  | 
|  4 | 2014-10-28  |
|  5 | 2014-10-28  |  
|  6 | 2014-10-26  |  
|  7 | 2014-10-25  | 
|  8 | 2014-10-23  | 
|  9 | 2014-10-22  | 
+----+-------------+
```

From this table, I want to get the last 5th day's startDate from current date. The date may not be consecutive I mean in this table my data will not enter everyday but whenever I want to check last 5th day from today it should return like '2014-10-23'. Please help me out.

Comment: Hi @Poles :  care to check answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Limit

```
SELECT startDate FROM table WHERE startDate <= CURDATE() ORDER BY startDate LIMIT 5,1
```

It means

1)Get records Whose start date is less than current date, and then

2) return one record starting at record 5(means get 5th record).

Answer (score 1):

your query will look something like this

```
select startDate
from table_name
where startDate <= CURDATE()
order by startDate desc limit 5,1
```

or

```
select startDate
from table_name
where startDate <= CURDATE()
order by startDate desc limit 1 offset 5
```

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird he said the last fifth day from today which yields to '2014-10-23' as per his description above